# In the biography of Turing by Hodges an ancient Celtic tradition is mentioned of killing the last to arrive

Tags: ancient-history, celts, human-sacrifice, torture

According to Hodges, Turing compared some modern custom to the torture and killing of the last to arrive at Celtic councils. I can find no other mention of this elsewhere; can anyone expand upon or at least substantiate this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a well known fact (or legend), told by Julius Caesar in his [Commentaries on the Gallic War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentarii_de_Bello_Gallico) (Original title, "De Bello Gallico") Chapter 5-56:

> quo lege communi omnes puberes armati convenire coguntur; qui ex iis novissimus convenit, in conspectu multitudinis omnibus cruciatibus adfectus necatur

which can be translated as

> Such is the custom of the Gauls in order to wage war: they oblige by law all
>   young men to present themselves armed, and to which the last one arrives, at sight of the whole council, they dismember him.

It's not completely sure that this custom was real in Caesar's times. Maybe it was merely a rumour that Caesar took for granted. This comes under the legends that the Celts (who included the Gauls) liked to tell about themselves. See [Táin Bó Cúailnge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A1in_B%C3%B3_C%C3%BAailnge) for an entertaining example.

Turing would have been familiar with Caesar's Commentaries on the Gallic War, because it was widely used in teaching Latin in Britain in the beginnings of 20th. Century. When he was 13 he was enrolled at [Sherbone School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherborne_School), whose teachers placed large emphasis to the classics.

Comment: And a few minutes after the killing, another guy shows up and everything gets kind of awkward.

Comment: I think this comes under the legends that the Celts (who included the Gauls) liked to tell about themselves. See [Táin Bó Cúailnge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A1in_B%C3%B3_C%C3%BAailnge) for an entertaining example. Turing would have been familiar with Cesar's [Commentaries on the Gallic War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentarii_de_Bello_Gallico), because it was widely used in teaching Latin.

Comment: @JohnDallman Your comment would improve mi answer a lot, but I'm quite newby and I don't know if I'm suposed to do it or you should make your own answer. ¿?

Comment: You're welcome to edit my material into your answer. I didn't know your main point, and if I wrote a separate answer, I'd have to crib from you to make it a complete one.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The Turing book is really a good one, expected to find this tidbit footnoted. And yes, Turing would have studied classics like many other English schoolboys aiming for university. I think Orwell and Roald Dahl (both near-contemporaries) mentioned having studied them.

Comment: I would also  add that from the Turing bio I got the impression that this was a meeting of government and the last senator or whatever was be killed; that it is a calling up of troops makes more sense.

Comment: @Joe: Sort of a Monty Pythonesque scene: No, I am no way the last to show up! I saw Angus -- he was helping his mom and said he would be here soon. Come on, can we give it a few minutes??

Comment: @Joe, just thinking: Not awkward at all -- they kill him too.

Comment: @Jeff comments are meant to be comments about improving the answer, so it is expected you will include them in your answer if you agree, it is nice to attribute them (but not essential) as comments can be short lived.